# Angular view not updating after model change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having an issue with AngularJS updating view elements following model changes. I have a form with 2 fields, and I want the user to fill in 1 of them, and have the other automatically filled (on ng-blur). The example I'm posting uses person name and social security number (SSN). By filling in the SSN the app carries out an HTTP call to fetch the name for that SSN, and vice-versa.

Here's the Angular directive:

```
define([
  'angular'
], function (angular) {
  angular.module('form.formDirective', [])
      .directive('formDirective', formDirective);

formDirective.$inject = ["$rootScope", "$sce", "$document", "$translate", "$filter", "$http"];

  function formDirective($rootScope, $sce, $document, $translate, $filter, $http) {

    var myLink = function ($scope, $element, attrs) {

        $scope.setFieldsForName = function(name) {
            var url = 'http://some.rest.api/getSsn/' + name;
            $http.get(url)
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.personSsn = data.SSN;
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  // no-op
                });
        };

        $scope.setFieldsForSsn = function(ssn) {
            var url = 'http://some.rest.api/getName/' + ssn;
            $http.get(url)
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.personSsn = data.name;
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  // no-op
                });
        };

    };

    return {
      templateUrl: 'form.directive.html',
      restrict   : 'EA',
      scope      : {
        field         : '=',
        model         : '=',
        renameChildKey: "=",
        preview       : "=",
        delete        : '&',
        ngDisabled    : "=",
        isEditData    : "="
      },
      replace    : true,
      link       : myLink
    };

  }
});
```

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<!-- Name -->
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"
       id="{{getId(0)}}"
       class="form-control"
       placeholder="Name"
       ng-model="personName"
       ng-blur="setFieldsForName(personName);"/>
</div>

<!-- SSN -->
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"
       id="{{getId(1)}}"
       class="form-control"
       placeholder="SSN"
       ng-model="personSsn"
       ng-blur="setFieldsForSsn(personSsn);"/>
</div>
```

This works perfectly for one case, e.g., fill in name and get SSN, or the other way around. But any attempt after that first one, what happens is the function is called, it fetches the data, updates the appropriate scope variable, but the input field value does not reflect the updated value of the variable.

I looked around and saw that $scope.$apply() is a popular solution, however, it doesn't work for me, I get an error stating that the code is already in a digest() stage, so it cannot run apply().

If you have an idea what's going on, I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Side note: Are you sure you know what `$q` is for? In your current implementation, the deferred calls are completely useless.

Comment: Try using this: $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
  $scope.personSsn = response.name;
})

Comment: @czosel, shortly, no. I copied this potential solution from somewhere else.

Comment: @LukeBecker I tried this, but didn't work. Before I was using $q I used just the default $http return conditions: .success / .error.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **$watch** for scope methods as the event will fire during **blur**. So $watch will look for any change binding expression particularly  which each change.

```
define([
  'angular'
], function (angular) {
  angular.module('form.formDirective', [])
      .directive('formDirective', formDirective);

formDirective.$inject = ["$rootScope", "$sce", "$document", "$translate", "$filter", "$http"];

  function formDirective($rootScope, $sce, $document, $translate, $filter, $http) {

    var myLink = function ($scope, $element, attrs) {
          //modified
        $scope.$watch.setFieldsForName = function(name) {
            var url = 'http://some.rest.api/getSsn/' + name;
            $http.get(url)
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.personSsn = data.SSN;  
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  // no-op
                });
        };
         //modified
        $scope.$watch.setFieldsForSsn = function(ssn) {
            var url = 'http://some.rest.api/getName/' + ssn;
            $http.get(url)
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.personSsn = data.name;     
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  // no-op
                });
        };

    };

    return {
      templateUrl: 'form.directive.html',
      restrict   : 'EA',
      scope      : {
        field         : '=',
        model         : '=',
        renameChildKey: "=",
        preview       : "=",
        delete        : '&',
        ngDisabled    : "=",
        isEditData    : "="
      },
      replace    : true,
      link       : myLink
    };
    }
    });
```

Explore $watch in detail. [HERE](http://www.learn-angular.org/#!/lessons/watch)

Comment: This won't work as it is, but I've explored $watch and did some experimentation. Unfortunately though, I've not been able to solve the problem.

Comment: What is that your getting? When u use this?

Comment: The functions (setFieldsForName and setFieldsForSsn) are no longer recognized from the HTML code.

Comment: @JoelA.Delgado Hi, do u still face problem?

Comment: @Aravind - Won't `$watch`-ing these functions cause the `$http` requests to fire needlessly, multiple times per `$digest` cycle?